# Google analytics not working in payment success page in Magento 1.9.3.7

Tags: checkout, payment, google-analytics, magento1.9.3.7

i am using Magento 1.9.3.7 and here i have add a google analytics code using admin panel. It is working fine everywhere but payment successfull page. What things are going wrong ?

Comment: Did you checked as a new customer see success page after order?

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my question. actually it is not displaying activities on success page.